# Bash while read and saving variables

Tags: bash, variables

I want to "parse" a textfile via bash and want to save several variables by doing this.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
#vlantag=""
#servername=""
kdip=""
#swport=""

cat test|while read line; do
    if [[ -z $kdip ]]; then
        kdip=$(echo $line | grep Kunden-IP-Adresse |
            grep 4948 | cut -d":" -f2 | tr -d ";" |
            sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//')
    fi
    #echo $kdip;
done

echo $kdip
```

What I want to do is grep line by line, save things like kdip globally and use these variables later on to use them to fill another textfile. Thing is, my last echo is empty. kdip is only valid in the "while-loop". How can I make the value of kdip permanent?

Answer (score 3):

Yours is basically a variant of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 but the whole script would benefit from a substantial refactoring which also coincidentally removes this problem.

```
kdip=$(awk -F ':' '/Kunden-IP-Adresse/ && /4948/ {
    k=$2; gsub(/;/,"",k) gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"",k);
    print k; exit(0) }' test)
```

If there are more variables you want to extract, just have the Awk script calculate them all and write them out in a suitable form -- in the worst case, one which you can `eval` from the shell, but if the values are suitably machine-readable, something like

```
set -- $(awk stuff ...)
kdip=$1
servername=$2
```

will work nicely -- just make sure the Awk script outputs the `kdip` value as the first field, server name second, etc.

Comment: I haven't tried to run it, but it appears that there's stuff missing from your code, eg the awk command is missing a `}`, and the `$(...)` is missing its closing `)`.